# Create link to new InfoPath Filler form

Tags: infopath

This has me stymied. I created an InfoPath form library and a form. I can add new items to it by clicking the New > New Document menu items in the MyItems page. I need to create a "quick link" to this on another page. Ideally, this link would have the same effect as choosing "New Document." As we only have the Standard version of Sharepoint, I can't generate a hyperlink based on the FormServer.aspx method (no web forms), which is the only solution I find on the web.

Is this impossible? What's the code on the MyItems page doing? I should be able to duplicate this, no?